# Minimum node modules

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

What minimum node modules do I require for simple project? Can I remove most of them manually or should I do

```
npm install [some minimum requirements]
```

I mean, common, I have a simple site of 5-10 pages and one of them is making http requests to services, I really don't need node modules folder of 90 MB in my small project.

Comment: What modules you need to install depends entirely upon what modules your project needs and no more.  We can't answer any specific questions about modules without seeing your entire code.  Don't install a module you don't need.  And, for server-side code, it matters not if you have 100MB in your node_modules folder.  It doesn't matter one iota.  It's just disk space which costs pennies.  Any modules that you aren't using is just sitting there like a library that isn't being used.  It has no cost at all to your application.  Only modules that are actually used are loaded into memory.

Comment: And, keep in mind there are many megabytes of modules built-into node.js too waiting for you to use them if you so choose.  Those aren't costing you either until you use them.

Comment: So typical, I get one downvote just for asking obvious question "why do we use so much disk space in vain"?
As for jfriend00 answer, I use some basic stuff: @angular dependencies (router, etc), http client etc. I really need my storage space :)

Comment: This is a very inefficient use of time to try to weed out disk space usage when building a server-side app.  You want to have the freedom to use as many modules as you find will make your coding life better and faster. 
 For $50, you can buy a 1TB drive on Amazon, for $60 a 2TB drive, for $80 a 3TB drive.  This is like going to a drag strip to race your buddy's car and worrying about how much gas you're going use in the 1/4 mile.  It's the wrong thing to be worrying about.

Comment: I'm not going to drag strip, I create a very simple website. I have my reasons that I need it to be like few MB tops.

Comment: Well, the only way anyone can help you trim it down to the bare essentials is to provide ALL your code and your existing node_modules directory so we can figure out what might not be needed or how you could change your code to use less.  If you want to absolutely minimize things for a simple web site, then you will probably need to remove frameworks and other 3rd party things and code just a simple web site yourself.  The whole advantage of node.js is that you can use the tools that others have built so you can build things very simply (without regard for how many MB those tools take).

Comment: If you want to optimize only for MB, then you will have to throw a bunch of helpful things away and code stuff yourself.  Frameworks contain a lot more than you are likely using.  Nobody can help you in any specific way without seeing exactly what your code is and what you currently have in your node_modules.  As such this question is going nowhere as it currently stands.

Comment: Nope, there is a way: I found out by try-catch method, here are the modules that are only needed for my small project (as I said, I have routing and calling service through http, that's just about everything I use in the app):  -.bin
 -@angular
 -reflect-metadata
 -rx
 -rxjs
 -systemjs
 -zone.js  My app runs fine just with those modules, I'm even sure I could reduce it even more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so whoever has simple Angular 2/4 project, and for some reason doesn't want to include all node modules in deployment package, I found these to be must-have node modules; my site works fine with just those:

```
-.bin
-@angular
-core-js
-reflect-metadata
-rx
-rxjs
-systemjs
-zone.js
```

In index file I have these references:

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>    
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

(Why I got the downvote just for saving disc space for people who can't afford much hosting, or who don't want to copy endless tiny files over the network... is beyond me)

Answer (score 1):

Your `ng build` will be a lot smaller for what you actually need to place on your server, only a few MB for a small website.

By default `npm install` will install only your **package.json** dependencies (and their sub-dependencies), and Angular CLI is fairly minimalist as far as included packages (assuming you're using it, which is highly recommended). Also, you can remove testing similar to this answer: [Completely removing tests from angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657372/completely-removing-tests-from-angular4/44657848#44657848), but not much else. The other piece is that you can also remove animations, even some of the other non-core items but unless your really tied for space I'd recommend leaving those packages alone.